# MySql Partitioning

Tags: mysql, partitioning, database-partitioning

I'm trying to create partitions in one big table, but I'm getting this error:

1505 - Partition management on a not partitioned table is not possible

There is any command to convert the table? Or do I have to create a new one and import all data?

There is any problem when using Partitioning with Replication?

Thanks in advance,
Pedro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name PARTITION BY ...
```

Comment: Well I get sintax error with:
ALTER TABLE promo_tool_view  
PARTITION BY (
  partition p001
)

Comment: Check the syntax for CREATE TABLE: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html Note that you're missing an argument that specifies what to partition by (hash, key, range, or list).

Comment: thank it worked with
ALTER TABLE promo_tool_view
PARTITION BY RANGE (date(view_date)) (
  partition p001 VALUES LESS THAN (date('2009-11-01'))
, partition p002 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE)
)

But now I get his partition function is not allowed, but I think is related with date function.